# JDBC Driver not take in when Build the project

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, odbc

I am execute mvn install command and every time given error like this.

[image]

As a reason , as i understand jdbc driver not configure with java. I had install MSSQL2017 server , and mvn setting.xml point to that server.
I need help to ,help how put JDBC driver to with in JDK tool kit or class path.(or if i can download java JDK with JDBC Driver) 
i am trying lot of time but still same error.

Comment: You need to configure first MSSQLServer drivers with JDBC.

Comment: This error is specific to that pom.xml, we can't help you with more information on that project itself.

Comment: @SPnL can you please help me configer sql server. I using MSSQL 2017 and when instalation it fail client SDK tool package too.